# Django - ForeignKey to model with multiple choices

Tags: python, sql, django

Sorry if the title is a bit unclear, I am a beginner and I have a few questions about database design.

I am building django app that would store info about a Book and another class Category that contains a list of genres. I would like to connect these tables so that one could choose category when inserting the book, **however the categories are not showing up (I'm using django forms).** Do you maybe know why?

```
CATEGORIES = (('Thriller', 'Thriller'), ...)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=CATEGORIES, default='Unknown')


class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    .......
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Or should I just include category inside the Book class and not connect them with ForeignKey? **What would be the pros and cons of this**? I already changed my DB few times splitting things up and again just putting it back to Book class as I don't really know what is better design in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: If the categories are *fixed*, and there are no other attributes, then it makes no sense to define an extra model. But the question remains: will the categories be *fixed*?

Comment: The categories are (likely) not showing up, because you did not define any categories (yet) in the database.

Comment: But do I need to insert them into DB even though I am including them as default  choices? What's the purpose of choices then? The other thing, I haven't really thought about keeping them fixed, however I am thinking about things like filtering through categories later on, etc. For this purpose, is it better to store them in the Book or seperate?

Comment: You should store the categories in Book. That will be more efficient.